# Difference between "" (Empty String) and isNot Nothing?

Tags: c#, if-statement, uipath, uipath-studio

I am working on a condition where I have to validate whether the argument is empty or not. Lets assume that argument is `Email`. I have to check whether the inwards argument Email is empty or not. I can do it in several way but I am not sure which one to proceed with.

I am thinking to check from following statement:

1.`Email = ""` to check if email is empty string or not. 
2. `Email isNot Nothing`

I wanna know the difference of these two functionality. If there are more function or argument related to validating empty string, You can write that too.

Thanks.

Comment: `Email isNot Nothing` is this vb.net?

Comment: or [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.8) which is sometimes better for user input (where *dirty little fingers* can add spaces)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String` is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), which means it **can** have a *null reference*

**Eg**

```
string myString = null;
```

It can also be *empty*, which is to say, there is a *reference* to it, and it has 0 character length

**Eg**

```
string myString = "";
// or
string myString = string.Empty;
```

And just for completeness, it can also have *white space*

**Eg**

```
string myString = "   ";
```

You can check for `null` like so

```
if(myString == null)
```

You can check for *empty*

```
if(myString == "")

// or

if(myString == string.Empty)
```

You can check for both, not `null` and not *empty*

```
if(myString != null && myString != string.Empty)
```

You could use [Null conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) with `Length` to check both is not `null` and not empty

```
if(myString?.Length > 0)
```

Or you can use the built in string methods, to make it a little easier

[String.IsNullOrEmpty(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8)

> Indicates whether the specified string is null or an empty string
>   ("").

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString))
```

[String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.8)

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only
>   of white-space characters.

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString))
```

<sub>***Note*** : It's worth noting, that `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` generally more robust when checking user input</sub>

Comment: Also note microsoft recommends to use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` or `IsNullOrEmpty` for  superior performance.

Comment: @bansi thanks for that, do you have any source/link for that so i can add it to the answer?

Comment: [CA1820: Test for empty strings using string length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1820?view=vs-2019)

Comment: `myString?.Length >= 0` will be true if your string is not null. To make it false when it's empty make a little fix `myString?.Length > 0`

Answer (score 3):

Actually in `C#` `string.Empty` is equivalent to `""`. See [String.Empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.empty?view=netframework-4.8)

Best way to check for `Empty` or `Null` strings is:

`string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email)` or you can use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email)` to additionally check for white spaces.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email))
{
    // Good to proceed....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use IsNot nothing with reference type variable. Instead, Use string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) together with String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email) while you need to validate email.